# Open Saved .Fig file into One Figure

Tags: matlab

I have two saved figures, `figure1.fig` and `figure2.fig`. I want to plot them on the same plot with different colors for comparison.

What I've managed to do so far is to plot them on the same graph, but with the same color:

```
fig1 = open('figure1.fig');
fig2 = open('figure2.fig');

axis1 = get(fig1, 'Children');
axis2 = get(fig2, 'Children');

for i = 1:numel(axis2)
    subAxis = get(axis2(i), 'Children');
    copyobj(subAxis, axis1(i));
end
```

How can I change the color now? To be concise, I do not have access to the actual signal; I only have the `.fig` files available.

Comment: Why not using the edit mode and your mouse (edit plot icon)? You copy, paste, delete graphical objects, and change their colors ...

Comment: Because, I have many, many files, and I don't want to manually open and edit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following. Call `copyobj` with an output argument. It refers to the handle of the copied object, in your case an axes. You can change the background color of this axes, or the color of the signal it encapsulates.

```
h1 = copyobj(subAxis, axis1(i));  % new handle for the copied object
set(h1, 'Color', 'g');            % change the background color to green
h2 = get(h1, 'Children');         % get the encapsulated handle of the signal within axes
set(h2, 'Color', 'k');            % change the signal to black
```